# What diagnostic steps should I take to fix this authorization?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am hitting a blocking issue where I cannot download the code for my app engine.
I have:

1. Run gcloud components update
2. Made an absolute path call to appcfg.py
3. Run gcloud auth login to confirm I'm logged into the right account.
4. Confirmed the app actually exists.

I've seen the unexpected characters u's~ at the beginning of the app id. It might have something to do with UTF8 vs a previous format but do not remember the remedy.

What diagnostic steps should I take to fix this authorization?

```
DarianMac:~ darianhickman$ ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py -A 'profound-ship-156505' -V '20170211t171524'   download_app ./download
07:01 PM Host: appengine.google.com
07:01 PM Fetching file list...
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~profound-ship-156505').
--- end server output ---
```

What diagnostic steps should I take to fix this authorization?

Comment: Try the same with `sudo`.

Comment: It's a not a local permissions thing.  It's definitely something regarding the gcloud login.

Comment: I would not suggest it if I did not have the same problem. The message is misleading.

Comment: I tried it and same error message: DarianMac:Documents darianhickman$ sudo ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py -A profound-ship-156505 -V 20170211t171524   download_app ./download
Password:
09:39 PM Host: appengine.google.com
09:39 PM Fetching file list...
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~profound-ship-156505').
--- end server output ---

Comment: Try absolute path for a download location. I had the same error message before, and the problem was that gcloud did not have the permissions to write to the local file directory. I don't know if that's the problem you face (hence comment, not an answer), but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted from email conversation with Google Cloud support:

> Pouyan Jazayeri  Feb 13
>
> to Darian  Hi,
>
> I am afraid the tool does not exist for node.js. It is only for Java,
>   Php, Go and Python. The languages supported on App engine standard.
>
> I can file a feature request for you if you wish.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Pouyan

Answer (score 1):

If you head into the cloud console is your user marked as a project owner?

From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code#permissions

Only the developer who uploaded the code and the application owner(s) can download it. If anyone other than these parties attempts to download the app, they'll see an error message like the following:

```
Fetching file list...
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to download this app version.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: Definitely the owner of the source.